# Plotly js selection event for parallel coordinates plot

Tags: javascript, events, plotly, parallel-coordinates

I am looking for a way to retrieve the selected data of a parallel coordinates plot created with Plotly.js every time the selection changes. A minimal JSFiddle example of my problem can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/5g9p49jq/

And I am struggling with these lines, as I do not know the correct event for a selection in a parallel coordinates plot (if there is one). The following does not work:

```
graphDiv.on('plotly_selected', function() {
  /*
    Event does not get emitted when selecting data on the parallel
    coordinates plot
  */
});
```

I created a parallel coordinates plot with Plotly.js following the official tutorial on their page:

https://plot.ly/javascript/parallel-coordinates-plot/

For retrieving the data I thought of using one of Plotly's events. I thought the Select Event might fit this purpose, but it seems that it is only meant to use for lasso selection (e.g. on scatter plots) not the selection in a parallel coordinates plot.

So my question is:

Is there an event emitted, when making a selection on a parallel coordinates plot or how else would I retrieve the data of my selection after the selection changed?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Comment: Hi, do you have any solution to your question? I'm new to plotly, and looking for solution to this exact question.

Comment: @user3794740 yes, I solved it somehow. It was quite some time ago, so I'm not 100% sure, how it worked. But I think I used the `plotly_restyle` event (https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#update-data), which gets emitted when you make a selection on an axis. Then either with the event data or with the data of the plot object it should be possible to determine the selected ranges. With these ranges you can filter your data. I hope my answer gives you a clue, what to try out.

Comment: as mentionned by @Symmetronic you can use plotly_restyle event. An additional clue is that you can use the returned object's key to see which dimension (which axis) was constrained. However this seems like a workaround rather than a robust solution. I think plotly should work more on their events.